# Unable to collect event into Splunk index

Tags: splunk

I am trying to create a summary index in Splunk 6.6.7, but unable to get data ingested using `collect` command.

I have manually enabled it in `savedsearches.conf` file.

After creating this, I have restarted my Splunk and tried to run the below query using `collect` command to ingest data.

The data is not getting ingested anytime.

```
[xxxx_capacity_threshold]
action.summary_index = true
action.summary_index._name = xxxxx
action.email.useNSSubject = 1
alert.track = 0
search = index="$param$-xxx" sourcetype="xxx" | table maxPercentage percentage
```

```
| makeresults | eval _raw = "{\"maxPercentage\":\"70\", \"percentage\":\"90\"}" | table _raw | collect index="xxxxxx-xx" file="new_settings_$timestamp$.stash" sourcetype="xxxxxx" addtime=true testmode=false
```

The expectation is that the data needs to get inserted in the index once the collect command is executed

Requesting to help me identify a solution to my problem.

Also, I am presently using an index say "1234-index" where I have different source types to cater to my needs. However, I have one particular source type for which I need to collect the summary data.
So is it necessary to create an entirely new index for the summary or can I just use the "1234-index" index and mark it to enable capturing summary data as well in a separate source type?

Thanks
Shahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write data using `collect` to any index (that you have access to). You can separate them by providing a unique source or sourcetype as part of the `collect command, however do note that changing these from the default may impact your license usage.

In terms of your other question, the job inspector should provide warnings or error messages as to why data was not being written. Can you share the details of that when you try a search.

Comment: Thank you @simon-duff for the response, the issue was the restriction on my setup where the collect command was not working as expected, when tried on other system, the solution did work.
Thanks Again,
Mohammed Shahid Nawaz